# context is not recognised inside run()

Tags: java, android, timer, android-asynctask, timertask

i have a TimerTask inside AsyncTask, the timer calls speakOut class posted below to pronounce text. when I used SpeakOut1 class the text was not 
pronounced at all, but when i used SpeakOut2 class the text pronounced as it should be.

in either cases i passed the context from the AsyncTask using getApplicationContext().

can any one explain why it did not work for the SpeakOut1 and it did in SpeakOut2?

please let em know how solve it

**SpeakOut1**:

```
private class SpeakOut extends TimerTask {

        private Context mCtx = null;
        private String mText = null;
        private TTSCtrl mTTS = null;

        public SpeakOut(Context ctx, String text) {
            this.mCtx = ctx;
            this.mText = text;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            this.mTTS = new TTSCtrl(this.mCtx);
            this.mTTS.pronounce(this.mText);
        }
    }
}
```

**SpeakOut2**:

```
private class SpeakOut extends TimerTask {

        private Context mCtx = null;
        private String mText = null;
        private TTSCtrl mTTS = null;

        public SpeakOut(Context ctx, String text) {
            this.mCtx = ctx;
            this.mText = text;
            this.mTTS = new TTSCtrl(ctx);
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            //this.mTTS = new TTSCtrl(this.mCtx);
            this.mTTS.pronounce(this.mText);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `SpeakOut.this.mTTS = new TTSCtrl(SpeakOut.this.mCtx);`

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK should i do that inside run()?...

Comment: Yes, Replace `//this.mTTS = new TTSCtrl(this.mCtx);` with `SpeakOut.this.mTTS = new TTSCtrl(SpeakOut.this.mCtx);`

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK but why that is happening

Comment: it is a class for text to speech

Comment: it is a wrapper around `TextToSpeech`? Are you subclassing it ? Btw it is possible that `TextToSpeech` is not ready yet to *speech* your text

Comment: can you post what exception you are getting from logcat?

Comment: @WalterM i am receiving no exceptions,...but the method .pronounce that should pronounce the text would not work